# Flexbox not wrapping as expected on Safari. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: css, safari, flexbox

I'm having a flexbox grid and it's not wrapping at all on Safari 7 (the one I'm testing).

This is a simplified example:

Html

`<ul>
  <li><a href="#">bla bla bla</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">bla bla bla</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">bla bla bla</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">bla bla bla</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">bla bla bla</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">bla bla bla</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">bla bla bla</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">bla bla bla</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">bla bla bla</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">bla bla bla</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">bla bla bla</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">bla bla bla</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">bla bla bla</a></li>
</ul>`

Css

```
ul {
   width: 100%;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li {
    background:red;
    width: 25%;
    height: 150px;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 4.0625rem;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
}
```

Here you have the code in a pen: [code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/apGXeg)

This is the result in Safari (screenshot made with Browserstack )

[image: bug]

I'm really stuck with this. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: looks ok to me http://i.imgur.com/g5bvdS7.png

Comment: My client is using Safari 7, and from what I saw, the layout is really messy. At this point, I'm wondering if it's a bug or if I'm a noob and not seeing something

Comment: Have you tried adding `display: -webkit-flex;` to `ul`?

Comment: Nope, autoprefixer added `display: -webkit-box;`. Indeed, `-webkit-flex` is doing the job. Right now I'm having other issues, but I guess that I have to manually fix them. Thanks! Can you post the comment as a answer so we can set this question as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safari 7 requires `-webkit` prefixes for flexbox properties. http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

You already have `display: -webkit-box;` on your `ul` but is another one that their version of Safari may want to use `display: -webkit-flex;`

Comment: yea, that's true. I'm using autoprefixer, and that takes care of prefixes. However, I just updated the pen and add `-webkit-` to the code, and the problem persists

Comment: @MarianIoan updated my answer to reflect `display: -webkit-flex`